# How can I use multi-word table names in laravel eloquent relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables.

```
my_categories -> id, name

my_tests -> id, my_category_id, title
```

MyTest model working like this:

```php
  class MyTest extends Model {
    use HasFactory;
    
    public function category() {
      return $this->belongsTo(MyCategory::class, 'my_category_id', 'id');
    }
  }
```

MyCategory model working like this:

```php
  class MyCategory extends Model {
    use HasFactory;
    
    public function tests() {
      return $this->hasMany(MyTest::class, 'id', 'my_category_id');
    }
  }
```

My migrations:

my_categories:

```php
      Schema::create('my_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
      });
```

my_tests:

```php
      Schema::create('my_tests', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('my_category_id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->timestamps();
        
        $table->foreign('my_category_id')->references('id')->on('my_categories')->onDelete('cascade');
      });
```

But I don't want rewrite 'id', 'my_category_id' everytime in relation functions. What are the default foreign keys of multiple words?

Also working like this but I have multi-words tables. There is no need add 'category_id', 'id' because its coming from default

```php
  class Test extends Model {
    use HasFactory;
    
    public function category() {
      return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
  }
```

```php
  class Category extends Model {
    use HasFactory;
    
    public function tests() {
      return $this->hasMany(Test::class);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just as you wrote:

> But I don't want rewrite 'id', 'my_category_id' everytime in relation functions. What are the default foreign keys of multiple words?

'my_category_id' would be the correct naming convention for table "my_category" in Laravel

Comment: What is the correct one for the my_categories table? I think my_category_id not default.

Comment: I already made a table like "companies" where my foreign key in the related table was "company_id" and that worked, so i guess this is how it is done